# How to send and update variable from python to html (Flask)?

Tags: python, html, image-processing, flask

I am creating a web application for a smart parking, it will have two buttons, which will show an image or frame of what the camera was looking at the moment of pressing it and the other will display a message which will tell the availability of each slot.

This is a part of the code that is responsible for finding availability in the parking lot, before I called a function that made me the perspective transformation to save code, but with flask I ended up generating problems when calling the method.

smartparking.py

```py
    def get_Disponibilidad(self):
        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame,(np.int(frame.shape[1]/2),np.int(frame.shape[0]/2)))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.circle(frame, (65, 190), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (490, 200), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (30, 310), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (530, 310), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        pts1 = np.float32([[65, 190], [490, 200], [30, 310], [530, 310]])
        pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [600, 0], [0, 500], [600, 500]])

        matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        result = cv2.warpPerspective(gray, matrix, (600, 500))

        v = np.median(result)    
        lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - 0.33) * v))
        upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + 0.33) * v))
    ##    edged = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 100)
        edges = cv2.Canny(result, lower, upper)

        estado = 0
        blancos = cv2.countNonZero(edges)
        if (blancos >= 6000):
            estado = 1
        #estado = disponibilidadPlaza(edges)
        return estado

    def get_Image(self):
        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame,(np.int(frame.shape[1]/2),np.int(frame.shape[0]/2)))        
        cv2.circle(frame, (65, 190), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (490, 200), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (30, 310), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (530, 310), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        pts1 = np.float32([[65, 190], [490, 200], [30, 310], [530, 310]])
        pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [600, 0], [0, 500], [600, 500]])

        matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        result = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, matrix, (600, 500))
        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

In the following code I call the function get_Availability () of smartparking, which should return a 1 in case of being busy and a 0 otherwise, this value is what should be shown in the html when pressing the button, but it should be update if the person presses the button when a car is found in the parking lot.

main.py

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, Response
from SmartParking import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():    
        return render_template('index.htm')

def disponible(parking):
        while True:                 
                availability = VideoCamera().get_Disponibilidad()
                render_template('index.htm',availability=availability)

def gen(camera):        
        while True:
                frame = camera.get_Image()                
                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Finally the html that now shows in real time what the camera sees, but the idea is to show a frame of the video each time the button is pressed, as well as the availability status.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Smart-Parking</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Smart Parking</h1> <h1 style="color: red;">LIVE STREAM</h1> 
    <img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">

    <h1>Slot 1:  {{availability}}</h1>

    <form method="POST"> 
      <button type="submit" name="Parking">Image</button>
      <button type="submit" name="Slots">Availability</button>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

The variable availability takes it as if it were null, and the buttons do not work either, since I do not know how to call them in the main.py

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

def disponible(parking) function has no route decorator and is never called.
You're rendering the template in the index function, which does not have the availability variable.

The form submission isn't being read anywhere either. You should look at flask's request context. Or at least point to a new route.

This will give you availability on refresh without requiring a button:

```py
@app.route('/')
def disponible(parking):
                availability = VideoCamera().get_Disponibilidad()
                render_template('index.htm',availability=availability)
```

The While True there would never work either since it immediately returns.

As for getting the buttons to trigger back to the program, you need to submit the form, and address that in the route that the form action points to. 
I.e. submit to a new route (/image) or use request to get the submitted arguments

```
@app.route('/image/)
# Do some action that you want as a result of the image button
```

with the form code in your template:

```html
<form name="image" action="/image"><button type=submit>image</button></form>
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/

Comment: But even so, the result found in the variable "availability" is not shown if it is the main.py, which is the same "estado" of smartparking.py, it should be 0 or 1.

Comment: get_Disponibilidad() is never called, since on a web view to '/', the only function that is called is index(), not disponible(parking). The render_template with availability never happens.

Comment: I'm already getting the value "availability" but in another route, I can put this value in a <h1> of the root path /?

Comment: Do you have other routes that you're not showing here? These could be helpful. As per your code that you're showing here, availability is only set in the disponible(parking) function, which is not being called as it has no route decorator.

Comment: ``def gen2(camera):        
        while True:
                availability = camera.get_Disponibilidad()               
                yield f'El estacionamiento se encuentra {availability}'


@app.route('/disponible')
def disponible():
        while True:                 
                return Response(gen2(VideoCamera()))`` The value is written and repeated many times in the route "/disponible", I'm doing the same as the video

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't make any sense. you have TWO functions named disponible?

Comment: If you have other functions and routes that are working with these elements then you need to post them. I still see nothing that will call ```render_template('index.htm',availability=availability)```